# Facebox adding commas to input

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I'm using a facebox to display a form inside a lightbox, nothing too exciting (just a couple of datepickers, some textboxes and a checkbox).
However, I'm having issues with the postbacks, whenever I post back from the facebox it adds a ',' to the start of the input (so "rabbit" becomes ",rabbit")
Now, I saw that there was the same issue with the modalpopup extender from the ajaxcontroltoolkit, so I assume it's a common issue.

Can anyone <strike>either explain *why* this is happening, or tell me how to fix it?</strike> provide a decent way of fixing this? I have actually done it, and it works very nicely, but I don't really want to answer my own bounty question so someone else give it a go!

Cheers, Ed

*EDIT*

See attached answer for a correct solution (I fixed this eventually but didn't want to ruin the bounty question so left the answer until afterwards).

Comment: I have no idea what facebox is (it sounds like some new and weird social networking site); but the reason for the ',' is probably you have two fields with the same name, and one of them is blank, but it gets passed into your control as two elements of a list. That's my psychic guess for tonight.

Comment: facebox is a jQuery lightbox plugin. It does actually create clones of all the control instances it contains, so perhaps that's the problem.

Comment: Most likely. Either give the controls different names, or simply find a way to split the string and deal with it appropriately.

Comment: Well, it's automatically cloned. The issue with this is that if you don't clone them it automatically disposes of the controls when it's closed, which is also bad! I can't seem to find the actual close function either, which is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you trim the output? simply remove the ',' for each string

Comment: Bad move: this could quite happily cause issues further down the line if I change the lightbox or use it on a different page, and is just another random chunk of hack to maintain. It's also supremely inelegant ;) Oh, and sometimes (when there's already content in the textboxes) it'll actually come out as "content,newcontent".

Comment: It's also supremely inelegant - this is correct I agree "but it works"

Comment: If we only ever went for "but it works" then we'd still be using BASIC and bicycles ;)

Comment: I think it is ALWAYS in the form "content,newcontent" and ",newcontent" is just a special case where the original content was blank. So splitting on the command may be correct, although you would obviously need some strategy to handle commas in the content itself.

Comment: BASIC and bicycles? Gold, I've now got a picture of a computer powered by a bicycle with the user riding and typing away!

Comment: I have actually fixed this but I'm not sure answering your own bounty question is acceptable so I'm going to give it until the end for someone else to come to a solution, then I'll post up the code etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have never programmed in ASP.NET or used facebox for that matter of fact, but here's a couple of solutions from my little research that might work.

There is a `reveal` function in the facebox source where the actual cloning is done:

```
reveal: function(data, klass) {
  $(document).trigger('beforeReveal.facebox')
  if (klass) $('#facebox .content').addClass(klass)
  $('#facebox .content').append(data) // <--- This does the cloning
```

The extra comma is obviously from the original form field that has been repeated. You could bind a click() function to the submit button that submits the form and in that function remove one of the clones. Since this function should run before the form data is processed, the duplicates should be taken care of.

```
$("#my-submit-button").click(function() { $('#facebox .content').empty(); }
```

If that doesn't work, then this surely will. Facebox has a bunch of hooks to run your code after various events. One of the hooks is `reveal.facebox` or `afterReveal.facebox`. Since the cloning is done on reveal, you would have to bind a custom function to run at this event, and in that function change the id/names of all elements. Append a random word like `_temp` or something for each element. Not the exact code, but I hope you get the idea.

```
(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function() {
    $("#facebox .content > *").each( 
        // change the id's/name's 
    );
});
```

**Edit**:

Looking at the html for Facebox examples, it looks like it lives inside its own `<div>` and copies anything that has to be shown within that div. So the structure of a sample facebox page could look like:

```
<html>
..
<form runat="server">

    <div id="myForm">
        // original form controls go here, probably hidden
        <input id="theId" type="text" value="" />
    </div>

    <div id="facebox">
        ...
        <div class="content">
            // the original form is copied inside this space and then displayed
            // this is the one the user interacts with and makes changes to
            <input id="theId" type="text" value="new value" />
        </div>
        ...
    </div>

</form>
..
</html>
```

So based on this structure and example, the input box with `id=theId` appears inside `div#myForm` and `div#facebox`. `div#facebox` is the one with the updated values that we need.

Comment: Yeah, I did something like what you've explained (this was a starting point), however I do have one comment with methods 1 and 2: If you remove/rename the inputs, ASP can't see them so you won't get their values :) I get that you're not an ASP guy so you wouldn't know that though, so +1 anyways, this could work in another language like php where you use post vars properly.

Comment: We are only renaming or removing one of the two inputs. I am guessing the .aspx server-side code binds to the input through the id attribute, so we leave one behind with the desired value and modify or take out the other one before submission. And thanks, I try to google my way out of problems :)

Comment: yup, as soon as the bounty's up: don't want to spoil the fun ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Here's how I fixed it:

changing 
    `function fillFaceboxFromHref(href, klass) {
....
        if (href.match(/#/)) {
            var url = window.location.href.split('#')[0]
            var target = href.replace(url, '')
            $.facebox.reveal($(target).clone().show(), klass)
....
    }`
to

    `function fillFaceboxFromHref(href, klass) {
....
        if (href.match(/#/)) {
            var url = window.location.href.split('#')[0]
            var target = href.replace(url, '')
            $.facebox.reveal($(target).show(), klass)
....
    }`

will stop it cloning the input and instead use the actual div.

Then, it's simply a case of re-appending the inner content to the #aspnetform (or #body as it originally used [you have to change that to allow asp.net postbacks]) before it's cleared in the close.facebox binding, like so:

    `$(document).bind('close.facebox', function() {
/// two added lines to add the content back to the #aspnetForm, with display:none; (i.e. invisible)
        $('#facebox .content').children().css({'display' : 'none'});
        $('#aspnetForm').append($('#facebox .content').html());
/// extra line to make sure there's no flashing effect as the facebox closes: the content is still in there too!
        $('#facebox .content').children().css({ 'display': 'block' });
....`

This will now use the original div as the content, avoiding the comma problem. However, if you wanted to use a div that is visible on the page originally then some extra twiddling would be needed in the close.facebox binding.