# facebox in asp.net cannot postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, facebox

i have an aspx page with feedback form which rendered inside facebox. In the form, i have a button which used to submit the form. After this, the facebox closes and its opening the page which is loading in the facebox in another page. I did go through many q&a here and tried on many suggested answers such as the link attached as below but unfortunately I still cannot figure it out.

http://weblogs.asp.net/kariemsoudy/archive/2009/11/02/buttons-inside-facebox-popup-don-t-postback-fix.aspx

[Facebox adding commas to input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027290/facebox-adding-commas-to-input)

Appreciate for any reply. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try sticking your app in an UpdatePanel so that when you postback in your section it's not posting back the entire site to FaceBook.  I'm not sure how your site is embedded into facebook, but if possible you might also try using iFrames to do the same thing (so that you're only posting back your frame, and not the entire facebook page).  My guess is that the postback to facebook results in your page being overwritten (by facebook).

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues with posting back, the easiest way to force the postback is to trigger the `__doPostBack` method as in:

```
__doPostBack('uniqueid', 'args');
```

Regardless of the issue with the button click, this should do the job.

Comment: it would be fired from some block of JavaScript code, possibly due because it has been attached to a JavaScript event.

Comment: @Brian Mains
but the facebox closes and its opening the page which is loading in the facebox in another page after postback.